# Evaluate function for observed $x, \dot{x}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

My question relates to a graphical approach to identifying the nonlinear terms of an oscillator [1].

The oscillator is

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x} + x + W(x,\dot{x})=0
\end{equation}

which [1] says can be written as

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2) + W(x,\dot{x})\dot{x} \, \, \mathrm{d}t =0
\end{equation}

or, equivalently, as

\begin{equation}
W(x,\dot{x})=-\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2)/2 \,\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

My questions are (i) how did the authors derive this equation and (ii) given observed values $x$ and estimated values $\dot{x}$, how does one evaluate $W(x,\dot{x})$ in a scripting language like MATLAB?

1. P.J. Beek, W.J. Beek, Tools for constructing dynamical models of rhythmic movement, Human Movement Science, Volume 7, Issues 2–4, October 1988, Pages 301-342, ISSN 0167-9457, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0167-9457(88)90015-2.
   (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167945788900152)

Update 1:

Using the advice of John Sinclair, we have that 
\begin{align}
\ddot{x} + x + W(x,\dot{x})&=0\\
\dot{x}\ddot{x} + x\dot{x} + W(x,\dot{x})\dot{x}&=0\\
\end{align}
and because
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}\ddot{x} + x\dot{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2)}{2\mathrm{d}t}
\end{equation}
we write
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2)}{2\mathrm{d}t} + W(x,\dot{x})\dot{x} &=0\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2)}{2} + W(x,\dot{x})\dot{x}\mathrm{d}t &=0\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2)}{2} + W(x,\dot{x})\mathrm{d}x &=0
\end{align}
from which we can get
\begin{equation}
W(x,\dot{x}) = -\frac{\mathrm{d}(x^2+\dot{x}^2)}{2\mathrm{d}x}
\end{equation}
which is the desired result.

Comment: Your first question is easy enough to answer: multiply the first equation through by $\dot{x}$, then integrate the first two terms.

Comment: How does one integrate just two of the terms? Do you mean write $\int \ddot{x}\dot{x} \, \mathrm{d}t + \int x\dot{x} \, \mathrm{dt} + \int W(x,\dot{x})\dot{x} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \int W(x,\dot{x})\dot{x} \, \mathrm{d}t =0$? How does one proceed from there?

Comment: You do it just like you see it in the 2nd equation: replace $\dot{x}\ddot{x} + x\dot{x}$ with $\frac{\mathrm{d}(\dot{x}^2 + x^2)}{2\mathrm{d}t}$, then multiply the whole equation through by $\mathrm{d}t$.